# Height issue for nested divs

Tags: html, css

Having a bit of trouble getting my nested divs lined up properly.  You can see an example of the code I'm working with on Dabblet:

http://dabblet.com/gist/6125817

I've run into the following issues:

1. The wrapper scrolls vertically.  I can live with this, but ideally I would rather it not.
2. The content needs to fill up most of the box.  If the wrapper takes up the screen, then the content needs to take up most of the space.
3. The footer needs to align itself to the bottom of the wrapper (plus bottom margin), not bottom: 0.

Everything I try seems to make something else fall out of whack.  I've been able to do parts of this when disabling other css classes.  Just can't get them to all work at the same time.

Just in case the link isn't working:

```
body, html {

}

body {
    background-image: url('/bground_home.png');
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-family: 'LegacySansUltra';
    font-size: 20px;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    background-color: white;
    border: solid 1px #666; 
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;

    margin: auto;
}

.header {
    font-size: 27px;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: Black;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 15px;
    color: White;
}

.content {
    width: 90%;
    height: 70%;
    position: relative;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #effbfb;
    border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border: 3px solid #e0f8fd;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.footer {
    background-color: black;
    padding: 5px;   
    color: White;
    margin: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 15px;
    height: 50px;
}


<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
        <div style="position: relative; float:left; width: {#logowidth}; height: {#logoheight}; padding: 0px 10px;">
            <img src="{#logo}" height="{#logoheight}" width="{#logowidth}" alt="{#name}" border="1" />
        </div>
        <div style="position: relative; float:left; padding-top: 20px;">
            {#name}
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="links">{#links}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe you could provide a picture with how you want it.  I find that to help out in css issues.  I see a bunch of ways to make it look nice, but it would take a bunch of questions to find out exactly what you want.

Comment: The dabblet link I provided should give you a general idea of what I'm trying to accomplish.  You'll need to go to the top of the page and be sure to click 'All' to see the preview, and code.

Comment: I know.  But here are some questions that I can only infer from the site, but I don't know your intention:  The header will expand height with its content, but the footer is a fixed height, is that what you want?    The content is a percentage of the wrapper but the header is dynamic based on its content and the footer is a static height.  Should the center content just expand to fill the area between header and footer, or is there a minimum height that should affect the whole wrapper?  So, a picture with call outs for what you want would help, because this is hard to explain in text sometimes

Comment: Also if you don't want the wrapper to scroll, do you want the blue content area to scroll or to make the wrapper larger, or to hide the overflow?

Comment: Footer and Header are fixed heights.  Only the Content will expand height as this needs to be viewable on numerous screen resolutions.

Footer/Header/Content/Wrapper all need to be variable widths.

Wrapper can scroll if the height is over 100%.  I just care that if the content isn't enough to fill the screen that it consumes the entire page height wise.

Comment: Is this for a whole page layout or just a widget that gets placed multiple times on pages?

Comment: Made the following changes and this seems to help with most of my challenges, but not all.

http://dabblet.com/gist/6135012

@DMoses

Comment: Only outstanding issues are:

1. Slight scroll at the bottom.  Again, not the end of the world and I can live with this.

2.  Need the content box to automatically be the full height of the page.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use this code:

   overflow: hidden;

Comment: Where does this go?  And which one of my problems does it fix?

Comment: Problem one. Put it in the wrapper class.